# Ubuntu Windows 10 Dual boot with TPM & Bitlocker

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, bitlocker

I have the factory installed copy of Windows 10 with Bitlocker enabled (I don't want to disable it), the EFI partition exists (System Reserved Partition). I installed Ubuntu 18.04 so I can dual boot, while installing I chose a 3 different partitions on my SSD for "/", "/home" and swap area. I chose to install the GRUB bootloader on the SSD as a whole not a specific partition on it so I guess that would make it install GRUB in the EFI partition?

Current state: boots into GRUB menu and if I chose Windows, it asks for the recovery key every time.

I want to uninstall grub and return to the Windows Bootloader/boot manager without reinstalling Windows. Then boot by default into it and have the option to chose to go to GRUB or Ubuntu directly as this tutorial https://stomp.colorado.edu/blog/blog/2011/12/05/on-dual-booting-tpm-linux-windows-and-bitlocker/ says.

Comment: YOur going to have to temporarily disable it if you want to be successful in this quest.  Recovery key is being asked for due to the config chnage

Comment: Did you previously have Secure Boot enabled? And do you still have it enabled?

Comment: Indeed Secure Boot have to be disabled during the Linux Setup, however, you can restore access to BitLocker protected device without disabling it. It is enough to temporarily make the Windows bootloader the first. See my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1278841/bitlocker-asking-for-protection-code-after-ubuntu-installation/1601666#1601666

Answer (score 1):

> I chose to install the GRUB bootloader on the SSD as a whole not a specific partition on it so I guess that would make it install GRUB in the EFI partition?

Yes it would. The question whether to install GRUB into a disk vs partition *doesn't even make sense* on UEFI.

> the EFI partition exists (System Reserved Partition)

That's not the same partition.

> I want to uninstall grub and return to the Windows Bootloader/boot manager without reinstalling Windows. Then boot by default into it and have the option to chose to go to GRUB or Ubuntu directly as this tutorial https://stomp.colorado.edu/blog/blog/2011/12/05/on-dual-booting-tpm-linux-windows-and-bitlocker/ says.

The tutorial is written for PC BIOS systems. **It does not apply to UEFI** – the special partitions are different, bootloaders live elsewhere, the whole boot process is nothing like BIOS boot.

For UEFI, the Windows Boot Manager *refuses* to start any other boot programs except for what comes with Windows itself. You can still add the corresponding entries, but they won't work.

However, for UEFI, your EFI System Partition already has both bootloaders installed and *the firmware itself* has a boot menu that allows you to choose between them. Hold <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> or whatever your computer uses; you'll find an entry for "Windows Boot Manager" and an entry for "Ubuntu".

Within Linux you can manage these boot entries using `efibootmgr`. For example:

```
# efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* Ubuntu
```

To swap them around (make Windows primary), you can again use the firmware settings screen, or you can change the BootOrder variable:

```
# efibootmgr --bootorder 0001,0000
```

To boot into Windows *once* while keeping Ubuntu as default, you can set BootNext:

```
# efibootmgr --bootnext 0000
```

And vice versa, if you're using Windows, to boot into Ubuntu just once:

1. Use `bcdedit /enum firmware` to find the Windows BCD GUID for the Ubuntu entry.
2. Use `bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} bootsequence {UBUNTU_GUID_HERE}` to program the BootNext variable.

Comment: Pressing F12 and accessing the boot sequence doesn't show options other than Ubuntu, in the EFI settings, the only boot option is Ubuntu and if I try to add another, I'm not sure what the options appearing mean but I do not see windows boot manager. In Windows I mounted the EFI partition, backed up the ubuntu folder in the C drive, then deleted it off the EFI partition. Then found out I cannot boot either OSs so I plugged the Ubuntu live disk and tried to restore that folder but silly me, the C drive has bitlocker enabled, I had to re-install Ubuntu to regain access to Windows.

Comment: You can have the double boot working without this clumsy "change boot order" all the time. See my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1278841/bitlocker-asking-for-protection-code-after-ubuntu-installation/1601666#1601666

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen: Unfortunately it seems that method requires using Microsoft-signed Shim and MOKs or the even-more clumsy hash enrollment in order to integrate Linux into Secure Boot, which might work well for Ubuntu, not so much for other distros. (In my experience trying to set up Shim was far more troublesome than any other option.) Whereas if you 
sign the boot manager with your own keys, Windows outright refuses to use PCR7 while "dual-booted" through it, complaining about untrusted keys in the Event Log... it will still use the TPM, but in the more fragile PCR0/2/4/11 mode.

Comment: Correct, I used the microsoft signed Shim indeed, with Archlinux. It is quite easy actually, and would work with any distro. The only complication is making sure to have a hook that sign your kernel when you update it. Better to enroll a MOK key and sign your binaries with it. Arch wiki explains the steps, which can be reproduced for any linux flavor and boot manager (except the auto sign hook). https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot#Set_up_shim

Comment: The rEFInd doc also provides good insights on how to setup Shim, even if you do not use rEFInd: https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html